# Select From One Table And Include Sum Value From Another

Tags: php, mysql

My title is terrible but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this.  I have two tables.  Links and Votes.  Links contain info about links submitted and the usual jazz, votes contains a foreign key link_id and a karma_up and karma_down value (both unsigned ints).  Because I want to limit votes to one per user and record vote time I opted for the two tables method.  What I want to do though is display the sum'ed karma of a link.  I need to be able to grab all the links and then their one to many votes which are sum'ed up SUM(karma_up - karma_down).  All I have been able to do is SUM up the entire column which doesn't do me any good.

Hopefully someone just "gets" what I'm trying to do but till then I will be updating this post with as much relevant information as possible.

**UPDATE**
For anyone interested, my final query is

```
SELECT links.*, (SUM(karma_up) - SUM(karma_down)) AS karma
FROM links, votes
WHERE links.id = votes.link_id
GROUP BY votes.link_id
```

Comment: Can you post your current `select` statement?

Comment: Son of a bitch you two are quick!  Awesome work, Kudos all around!

Comment: The idea (in one of the answers) is true, links will not be returned for those that have no votes. To get those you will need to use a left outer join.

Comment: Yea, I only went with the first answer because I insert a default vote for every new link with the *assumption*  that a user would vote for his own submission.  The unintended consequence of that was the simplification of this query :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could post your schema to be sure, but something like this should work

```
select v.link_id, (sum(karma_up) - sum(karma_down)) as points from 
Links l, Votes v
where l.link_id = v.link_id group by v.link_id
```

That should give you the points per link_id.

Comment: Beat me to it :) You may want to add an outer join, if links with no votes are needed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this:

```
SELECT Links.LinkId, SUM(Votes.karma_up) - SUM(Votes.karma_down) AS karma FROM Links
    LEFT JOIN Votes ON Links.LinkId = Votes.LinkId
    GROUP BY Links.LinkId
```

Note the use of LEFT JOIN to ensure that links without votes are also included.

Comment: I like this too, I don't quite need this because when I insert a link I also insert a default +1 karma vote so every link has at least one starting vote row.  A point regardless!

Answer (score 1):

Just one more thing I'd like to mention. Unless a vote is allowed to have both up and down karma at the same time (unlikely from the desription), you would better off replacing them `karma_up` and `karma_down` with a single `karma_delta` column. Then set it to -1 or 1 depending on whether it's down or up respectively.

This would simplify your query even more:

```
SELECT links.*, SUM(karma_delta) AS karma
FROM links, votes
WHERE links.id = votes.link_id
GROUP BY votes.link_id
```

Comment: That's a good idea.  I got the karma_up and karma_down idea for when they were attached to the link table itself but I wanted to see how many up/down votes there were and implement a duplicate check so I'll make those changes!

Answer (score 0):

Points per link id, and zero karma if there are no votes:

```
select l.*, coalesce(sub_karma, 0) as karma
from links as l
    left join (
        select link_id, sum(karma_up - karma_down) as sub_karma
        from votes
        group by link_id
    ) as v using (link_id)
;
```

Comment: Same comment as above although I understand yours slightly less, a point regardless!

Comment: The left join () as v is a sub-query to do the summing separately before joining to the links table.  paxdiablo's suggestion to use karma_delta is a better approach.  Simpler query to write and easier for the query optimizer (MySQL) to execute efficiently.